# Using App Settings in Azure Cloud for ASP.net site Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0

I was following some instructions on how to develop ASP.NET MVC applications, and I am adding the ability to log in using Facebook or Google.

I have heard that storing sensitive information in source code is bad practice. I modified my Web.config file like so:

```
<appSettings>    
    <add key="GoogClientID" value="X" />
    <add key="GoogClientSecret" value="X" />
    <add key="FbAppID" value="X" />
    <add key="FbAppSecret" value="X" />
    ...etc...
```

this prevents me from storing sensitive information in the source code, and I was intending to override them by configuring the app in the Azure portal.

I access these settings from Startup.Auth.cs, whcih from my understanding is typical for this type of application.

```
        //load from Web.config, to get app secrets.
        System.Configuration.Configuration WebConfigForSecrets = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
        if (WebConfigForSecrets.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
        {

            //google
            System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement GoogClientID = WebConfigForSecrets.AppSettings.Settings["GoogClientID"];
            if (GoogClientID != null)
            {
                System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement GoogClientSecret = WebConfigForSecrets.AppSettings.Settings["GoogClientSecret"];
                if (GoogClientSecret != null)
                {
                    //never reached when hosted on azure               
                    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(
                        clientId: GoogClientID.Value.ToString(), //added .Value 3/9/16
                        clientSecret: GoogClientSecret.Value.ToString()); //added .Value 3/9/16
                }
            }

            //facebook
            System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement FbAppID = WebConfigForSecrets.AppSettings.Settings["FbAppID"];
            if (FbAppID != null)
            {
                System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement FbAppSecret = WebConfigForSecrets.AppSettings.Settings["FbAppSecret"];
                if (FbAppSecret != null)
                {
                    //never reached when hosted on azure     
                    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                       appId: FbAppID.Value.ToString(), //added .Value 3/9/16
                       appSecret: FbAppSecret.Value.ToString()); //added .Value 3/9/16
                }
            }

        }
```

I tried to add the same key/value pairs to the "Application Settings" > "App settings"  menu in the azure portal for my web application. It still acts as if it is not finding them.

I also tried going to Project -> Publish Web.config from visual studio. It said it was successful, but it didn't solve the issue.

I have also tried using an absolute path for the AppSettingsSecrets.config file, but I have not tried adding it to the project, since that seems like it may defeat the purpose suggested in the article.

Does anyone know how to do this / what the best practice is when it comes to this?